# Question about oracle db connection with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, database, oracle, connection

I'm trying to connect to an oracle database with .net but i get the error:

```
ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

however, when I enter add a new database connection through tools>connect to database.  it works fine.  even after copying the connection string which is:

```
Data Source=source here;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userhere;Password=pass;Unicode=True
```

Answer (score 0):

What driver are you using? It looks from the error message that that you're going through ODBC. I believe the tools>connect to database use OLEDB drivers.

The connection string provided doesn't look like an odbc connection string.

Can you post a snippit of code showing how you're setting up the connection?

Thanks

Andrew